# Using Self Code Signing Certificates for Publish purpose

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I searched many times in this topic but with no luck, I have an application on WPF that use Click Once to published and there fore I can't use Admin Privilege, and I need to implement some actions in the installation Process like restart SQL server for example and for that I need Admin Privilege and since i start publishing using click once I had to remove Admin Privilege now, i tried restart my application to force Admin rights using the following code but didn't work

```
Public Function IsRunAsAdmin() As Boolean
    Try
        Dim id As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
        Dim principal As WindowsPrincipal = New WindowsPrincipal(id)
        Return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
    Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Public Sub AdminRelauncher()
    If Not IsRunAsAdmin() Then
        Dim proc As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        Dim procExecuting As New Process
        proc.UseShellExecute = True
        proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory
        proc.FileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase
        proc.Verb = "runas"
        Try
            procExecuting = Process.Start(proc)
            Application.ExitThread()
            Application.Exit()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("This program must be run as an administrator! " & vbLf & vbLf & ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

I still get the Error "Can not open MSSQL$****** on computer" after i searched of course i found the cause is admin rights needed.
So now i'm working on Code Signing Certificates as some one advise me that this will work for me.
but i'm an individual and my application price is not high enough to buy a paid certificate so i was wondering if i can make a self Code Signing Certificate and use it with click once.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manged to figure out the problem my self, it was the admin rights.
The problem was that the code simply need like 2-3 mile seconds to execute so when i tracked the code  i found that my code manged to stop the service indeed but wasn't able to start it again as it didn't take the time for the service to fully stop.

The solution was simple as it just needed couple of seconds to after it execute the code to stop the service.

So simply need to add a code in between.
First

```
Imports System.Threading
```

Then use the code as following

```
Dim service As ServiceController = New ServiceController("SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)")
                    service.Stop()
                    Thread.Sleep(10000)
                    service.Start()
```

You see the code where Thread.sleep is make the application wait 10 seconds before it complete to execute the code.

This time is depends on the machine it self, 2-3 sec was enough but some other machine needed more time so to be in the safe side just add more seconds as I did.

Thank you, and "Stay Safe".